# How to get Fullsize & Cycle - JQuery - working together?

Tags: jquery, cycle

I have a problem implementing too JQuery tools; Cycle and Fullsize (together).

I have uploaded an example over at: http://lawrencebrown.eu/jquery/index.html

The problem is that only the first image pics up the Full size script, I have bene told by a friend to add the following into code into the cycle script:

`?after: function () {
  $("div.album img").fullsize();
}`

I have tried putting this in different places from lines 19 to 43 on index.html with no winning results yet.

Any help you can offer to the mark up between lines 19 to 43 would be great.

I appreciate that their are plenty of other lightbox solutions that can solve this problem - I have even had a few up and running, however this is a specific request on this job to use Fullsize.

Thanks for you time

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is right. Just place it like this after `pagerAnchorBuilder` (note the additional colon before after)

```
$(function() {
  $('.album').before('<ul id="nav">').cycle({
  ...
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
      return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="42" height="33" /></a></li>';
    },
    after: function () {  $("div.album img").fullsize(); }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks jitter, I have updated the code using that mark-up – still getting the same problem though unfortunatly